# How to add Logout from all other session

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, jsp, session

My scenario is there are two different users login with same user id and password.mean time one of the person change the password by giving the current password. And changed the password at same time the another user gives current password what he logged in was incorrect. So i wants to add logout from all other devices in my web application.how can i do that

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).

Comment: But the scenario i have to explain.. and i have no idea how to do that

Comment: You need to share code. If not for this at least you can share how you creating session where are you storing data etc

Comment: why don't you just setup multiple users ?

Comment: i am using MySQL to store  users data.. and i not creating any session at all..

Comment: As a host how do i invalidate the user if the user request to invalidate the session

Comment: _and i not creating any session at all_ - how do you know which user is logged id then? There must be some login code, share it.

Comment: i added their name in session attribute..

Comment: `HttpSession ss = request.getSession();
if(isUser(name,password)){
ss.setAttribute("user",name)
}`

this is what i done in my servlet code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is of course more than one approach, my first idea would be to hook the sessions to the [ServletContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html). Something like

```
// this can be in some util class, let's call it SessionUtil
static final String SESSION_REGISTER = "session.register";
public static synchronized void registerSession(ServletRequest req, HttpSession ses, String userName) {
  ServletContext ctx = req.getServletContext();
  Map<String, List<HttpSession>> register = (Map<String, List<HttpSession>>) ctx.getAttribute(SESSION_REGISTER);
  if (register == null) {
    register = new HashMap<>();
    ctx.setAttribute(SESSION_REGISTER, register);
  }
  List<HttpSession> sessions = register.computeIfAbsent(userName, k -> new ArrayList<>());
  sessions.add(ses);
}
```

Then, in your code, you need to register the user's session after login:

```
HttpSession ss = request.getSession(); 
if (isUser(name,password)) { 
  ss.setAttribute("user",name) 
  SessionUtil.registerSession(request, ss, name);
}
```

Finally, you need a method (again in `SessionUtil` class) to invalidate all the user's sessions (except the current one):

```
public static synchronized void invalidateSessions(ServletRequest req, HttpSession current, String userName) {
  ServletContext ctx = req.getServletContext();
  Map<String, List<HttpSession>> register = (Map<String, List<HttpSession>>) ctx.getAttribute(SESSION_REGISTER);
  if (register != null) {
    List<HttpSession> sessions = register.get(userName);
    if (sessions != null) {
      for (HttpSession ses : sessions) {
        if (!ses.equals(current)) {
          ses.invalidate();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can call this method e.g. when the user changes his/her password.

**Note #1:** Not a very nice code, it misses some sanity checks and `synchronized` can be smaller chunks of code. It's just to give you an idea.

**Note #2:** The functionality of the `registerSession(...)` method can be done using the [HttpSessionAttributeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionAttributeListener.html), but I've never used it yet, so cannot give an example.